# Canon Pixma B200 error; what is it and can I fix it?

Tags: printer, colors

I have an MG 5300 series Canon Pixma printer.  Halfway through printing a page, an error - B200 -came up and it says:

> printer error has occurred.  Unplug the power cord and contact the service center.

Is this something that I can fix?

Comment: See this link: http://fix-your-printer.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-fix-error-b200-on-canon-printers.html

Comment: Total long-shot but... did you consider contacting the service center?

Answer (score 0):

Found the following on the [Cannon Community forum](http://community.usa.canon.com/t5/Printer-Multifunction-Support/error-b200/td-p/217);

> Please try the following to see if we can resolve your issue:
>
> 1. Open the cover of the printer.
> 2. Remove all ink tanks from the printer.
> 3. Lift up the gray locking lever on the side of the ink tank holder.
> 4. Gently remove the print head from the carriage unit.
> 5. Place the print head back in and lock the lever down.
> 6. Place all of the ink tanks back in the printer.
> 7. Close the cover and turn the printer off.
> 8. Unplug the power from the printer.  Leave the power unplugged for about 5-10 minutes.
> 9. Plug the power back in and turn the printer on.
>
> If the error persists, please contact a technical support
>   representative at 1-800-652-2666 between the hours of 10 AM and 10 PM,
>   EST, Monday - Friday for additional help with this error.

Some have noted that leaving the printer unplugged over night after completing the above steps has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is general error which occurs to all canon printers just after warranty is over. It does not depend if you have printed 50 or 1000 pages. The printer will broke. You can buy new print head, but is is better (almost same price) to buy new printer.

It is said 
1. The problem is with burned date wire in print head.
2. that cannon printers are crapped and they will end their lifetime with B200 error.

Answer (score -1):

Use the "deep clean" option in printer maintenance. Takes a lot of ink but it works quickly without dismantling anything!

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this will solve the problem? The error message says nothing about the printer needing cleaning and says that the printer should not be used; you're recommending using the printer intensively. That sounds like it could make the problem a lot worse, rather than fixing it.